# How to execute Data Transfer API?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk, google-data-api

I have few accounts where I need to transfer the ownership to another account. I have the list listed in google sheets with all the email addresses. I am using the code below to hopefully execute it but I am not sure what to use to execute the code.

```
function dataTransfer() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SHEETID")
      var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("SHEETNAME");
      var start = 2;
      var end = sheet.getLastRow();
      
      var range = sheet.getRange(start,1,end,sheet.getLastColumn());
      var values = range.getValues();
      
      for (var i = 0; i < values.length-1; i++) {
        
        /* transfer the data ownership to */
        var A = "aUser@company1.com";
        var B = "bUser@company1.com";
        var C = "cUser@company1.com";
       
        var email = values[i][0];
        var company = values[i][1];
        var status = values[i][3];
        
        if (status === "Complete") {continue;}
        
        if (company == "A") {
            /* transfer of the ownership of user data between users. */
          var transferObject = {
            "kind": "admin#datatransfer#DataTransfer",
            "oldOwnerUserId": email,
            "newOwnerUserId": A,
            "applicationDataTransfers": [
              {
                "applicationId": XXXXXX,
                "applicationTransferParams": [{
                  "key": "PRIVACY_LEVEL",
                  "value": [
                    "PRIVATE",
                    "SHARED"
                  ]
                }],     
              "applicationId": XXXXX,
                "applicationTransferParams": [{
                  "key": "RELEASE_RESOURCES",
                  "value": true
                }],
              }],
          }
          **admin.datatransfer....** /* what do I use here to execute the above code */
          sheet.getRange(start+i,4,1,1).setValue("Complete");      
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Using `UrlFetchApp` you need to make a `POST` request to `https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/datatransfer/v1/transfers`. You have to set up a GCP Project and enable the Data Transfer API to do this.*

#### More Information:

The prerequisites for using the Data Transfer API, as per [this page](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/data-transfer/v1/guides/prerequisites) state (emphasis my own):

> You need the following basic configuration before you can use the Data Transfer API:
>
> - Have a Google account and create an administrator. The API applies to Google Workspace, Education, Government, Reseller, and ISP accounts.
> - Be familiar with your Google Workspace Admin console found at admin.google.com. For more information about the Admin console, see Use your Admin console.
> - **Enable API access from the Google Workspace Admin console in order to make requests to the Data Transfer API.**

You can do this by going to [console.cloud.google.com](https://console.cloud.google.com) and creating a new project from the drop-down menu next to `Google Cloud Platform` on the upper menu bar.

Then, using the hamburger menu follow `≡ > APIs & Services > Library` and search for `Admin SDK API`. Click on the matching result, and on the new page click the `ENABLE` button.

Next, you will need to link this GCP Project to your Apps Script Project.

Going back to the Hamburger menu, follow `≡ > Home > Dashboard` and copy the 12-digit project number displayed in under the `Project info` area.

Going back to your Script, follow the `Resources > Cloud Platform project...` menu item, paste in that 12-digit number and click `Set Project`. This will link your Apps Script Project to the newly created GCP project wit the enabled API.

You can safely close this modal now.

As per the documentation on the [`transfers.insert` method](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/data-transfer/reference/rest/v1/transfers/insert):

> Inserts a data transfer request.
>
> #### HTTP request
>
> `POST https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/datatransfer/v1/transfers`
>
> #### Request body
>
> The request body contains an instance of [`DataTransfer`](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/data-transfer/reference/rest/v1/transfers#DataTransfer).

#### Code:

Firstly, as a quick code fix, the `applicationDataTransfers/applicationTransferParams/value` needs to be an [array of strings](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/data-transfer/reference/rest/v1/ApplicationTransferParam), and so should be:

```
"applicationId": XXXXX,
  "applicationTransferParams": [
    {
      "key": "RELEASE_RESOURCES",
      "value": [
        "TRUE"
      ]
    }
  ],
// ...
```

As well as this, the `oldOwnerUserId` and `newOwnerUserId` values must be the user ID values obtained from the [`users.list`](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/list) endpoint. The Google email address ***does not work*** as a replacement for this. A full example request would be as follows:

```
var payload = {
  "kind": "admin#datatransfer#DataTransfer",
  "oldOwnerUserId": "113412843513541354193",
  "newOwnerUserId": "118387348413214353832",
  "applicationDataTransfers": [
    {
      "applicationId": "14186345432",
      "applicationTransferParams": [
        {
          "key": "PRIVACY_LEVEL",
          "value": [
            "PRIVATE",
            "SHARED"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "applicationId": "546343454353",
      "applicationTransferParams": [
        {
          "key": "RELEASE_RESOURCES",
          "value": [
            "TRUE"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

As for making the `HTTP` request:

```js
const url = "https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/datatransfer/v1/transfers"; 
  
var headers ={
  "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
};
    
var options = {
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": headers,
  "contentType": "application/json",
  "payload": JSON.stringify(payload)
};
```

**Important Note:** As you are using the API directly with the Script's token as your OAuth Token, you will need to update the Apps Script manifest with your required scopes.

Follow the `View > Show manifest file` menu item, and add your scopes to the project. The full manifest file should look something like this:

```
{
  "timeZone": "Europe/Paris",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.datatransfer"
  ]
}
```

The `script.external_request` is required so you can call `UrlFetchApp`, and the `admin.datatransfer` is the scope required to make the call to the directory insert endpoint.

#### References:

- [ApplicationTransferParam | Data Transfer API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/data-transfer/reference/rest/v1/ApplicationTransferParam)
- [Google Cloud Platform](https://console.cloud.google.com)
- [Prerequisites | Data Transfer API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/data-transfer/v1/guides/prerequisites)
- [Method: Transfers.insert | Data Transfer API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/data-transfer/reference/rest/v1/transfers/insert)
- [REST Resource: transfers | Data Transfer API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/data-transfer/reference/rest/v1/transfers)
- [Method: users.list | Directory API | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/users/list)
- [Class UrlFetchApp | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)
- [Class ScriptApp | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app)

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an instruction on the exact same use case, and I found Rafas answer informative, but there is a simpler way to do this. So to help my Fellow scripters I've wrote a complete instruction below.

First of all, it can be done in Apps Script with the standard GCP account, so no need to meddle with Google Cloud Console. You do however need to have a super admin account in Google Workspace.

You also need to add the Admin SDK API to the project and enable it. Click on the plus sign to the right of "Services" when in the editor and add the API from the list.

Then you open the project settings (cog wheel on the left) and enable "Show manifest appsscript.json in the editor", go back to the editor, open appsscript.json and add

```
    "oauthScopes": [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.datatransfer",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly"
    ]
```

The reason you need to do this manually is that Apps Script won't detect the needed scopes automatically when we use the UrlFetchApp.
The appsscript.json should then look something like:

```
{
  "timeZone": "Europe/Berlin",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "AdminDirectory",
        "version": "directory_v1",
        "serviceId": "admin"
      }
    ]
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.datatransfer",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly"
  ]
}
```

I completed the snippets from the previous response, and the complete code to transfer all data from user A to user B would look like this. :-)

(Note that the applicationIds for the data transfer has [changed](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/data-transfer/v1/parameters))

```
/**
 * Source and target primary email for the data that should move
 */
function transferData(sourceEmail, targetEmail) {
  let sourceID=getUserID(sourceEmail);
  let targetID=getUserID(targetEmail);
  const url = "https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/datatransfer/v1/transfers"; 
  let payload=buildPayload(sourceID,targetID);
  let headers ={
    "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken(),
  };
    
  let param = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: headers,
    contentType: "application/json",
    payload: JSON.stringify(payload)
  };    
  let done=false;
  do{
    try {
      let response = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,param).getContentText());
      Logger.log(JSON.stringify(response).getContentText());
      done=true;
    }
    catch (e) {
      Utilities.sleep(500);
      
    }
  }while (!done)
    
}


function buildPayload (sourceUserId, targetUserId) {
  let payload = {
  kind: "admin#datatransfer#DataTransfer",
  oldOwnerUserId: sourceUserId,
  newOwnerUserId: targetUserId,
  applicationDataTransfers: [
    {
        applicationId: "55656082996",
        applicationTransferParams: [
          {
            key: "PRIVACY_LEVEL",
            value: [
              "PRIVATE",
              "SHARED"
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        applicationId: "435070579839",
        applicationTransferParams: [
          {
            key: "RELEASE_RESOURCES",
            value: [
              "TRUE"
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
  return payload;
}

function getUserID(primaryEmail)
{
  return AdminDirectory.Users.get(primaryEmail).id;
}
```