# Script to transfer user data to (for example, a md@org.com) after deleting a user account from G Suite Admin SDK

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk, google-workspace

I'm trying to develop a google script to transfer user data to (for example, a md@org.com), after deleting a user account from G Suite Admin SDK.
I've tried and am unable to find it anywhere the script to transfer user data after google mail deletion.
[image]

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
 deleteUsers(e);
}
function deleteUsers() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1Z0cNwh2BJLrq1bMQS3eU1tWLrjz2DLUne8CY3rMM7OE');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Delete Users');
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  var len = data.length;

  for(var i=1; i<len; i++){
    var user = data[i][0];
    var transferToEmail = data["Transfer to Email"][1];
    Logger.log(user);

    //use try catch in case a user is already removed
    try{
      AdminDirectory.Users.remove(user);
    }
    catch(err){}
  }
}
```

Comment: Please specify what do you mean exactly, are you referring to [Transfer data between Google Workspace accounts](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1041297?hl=en) or using the 
[Data Transfer API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/data-transfer)

Comment: @Emel I've attached the image, using the script I need to transfer data from one user(while deleting that account) to another user account.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to execute Data Transfer API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65227750/how-to-execute-data-transfer-api)

Comment: @Emel No, they're using GCP. Here, the above script will delete the listed mail ids in the google sheet. Along with that, I'll provide a mail id, to which the deleted mail ids google drive data should be transferred. I think it's possible by updating the above script alone. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: As explained in the linked question, you need to use the Data Transfer API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some Google APIs are integrated with Google Apps Script as advanced services, unfortunately the Data Transfer API isn't, that is why on [How to execute Data Transfer API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65227750/how-to-execute-data-transfer-api) are using `UrlFetchApp` to make a HTTP request to call the Data Transfer API instead of something like `AdminDirectory` to call the Directory API / Reports API.